# Javascript - prevent URL from being unescaped

Tags: javascript

This might sound like a very silly question but I ran into something and have no clue as to what to do at the moment. Surprisingly, I could not find anything via Google (I did it wrong, for sure).

For example:

```
javascript:alert('%62%6D%69');
```

outputs `bmi`. How to make it output `%62%6D%69`?

Thanks for helping me out here.

Comment: In what browser? Works perfectly fine for me in Chrome -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Lf2cs/

Comment: In what context are you using this?  In pure Javascript, this appears to stay encoded.


http://jsfiddle.net/qCy82/

Comment: Using Firefox 28.0 (Windows 7) at the moment. I want to do some nasty stuff like `javascript:location='data:text/html,<script type="text/javascript">document.write(unescape(\'%62%6D%69\'));</scr'+'ipt>'`. So I want the source code to be kinda "obfuscied". That's quite useless however, if those escaped characters are being unescaped before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this in your browser url `javascript:alert("%2562%256D%2569")`. Escaped it again.

Programmatically,

```
var x = escape("%62%6D%69");
location.href = "javascript:alert('"+x+"')";
```

or

```
location.href = encodeURI("javascript:alert('%62%6D%69')")
```

or inception mode

```
location.href = encodeURI("javascript:alert('%62%6D%69'); location.href = encodeURI(\"javascript:alert('%62%6D%69')\")")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: encodeURI seems to be helpful for what I am doing. Thanks.